# What does 今はそれだけじゃなかった mean here?

Tags: grammar, meaning

> 「あ、掃除の途中でしたか？」
>
> 「いや。これを拭くのは二度目だから。実はもう終わってるよ」
>
> 「そうですか。でっ、では……もう出発できるんですね」
>
> 「うん、大丈夫。常陸さんも、もう出れる？」
>
> 「はい。準備はできています」
>
> 「そっか……」
>
> 「それじゃあ、出発する？」
>
> 「はっ、はい。そうですね」
>
> なんてことはない、ただのやり取り。
>
> 学院に行くときだって、同じようなことを言ったことがある。
>
> でも、**今はそれだけじゃなかった**。
>
> これから２人で過ごす時間に、胸が複雑に高鳴る。
>
> ドキドキとした緊張、不安……と同時に、昂揚感とでもいうのだろうか？
>
> 間違いなく気持ちが高ぶっている。

If its not obvious from the above context, they have the above exchange before they go out on a date. My question is about what is meant by 今はそれだけじゃなかった. What is the それだけ actually referring to? (It seems to be referring to the line of なんてことはない、ただのやり取り, but I'm not quite sure what is trying to be conveyed.)

Answer (score 3):

this is the main characters  internal monologue (I suppose)

なんてことはない、ただのやり取り

He/she is thinking about the conversation they just had (or are) having.

学院に行くときだって、同じようなことを言ったことがある

This is thinking about earlier events where they have had similar conversations

でも、今はそれだけじゃなかった。

this is the person realizing that it's not the same, and that's everything feels different now that they are going on a date (and even just a simple conversation that was nothing earlier now gets his/her heart to beat faster)

and the words/thoughts cause the effect described here

これから２人で過ごす時間に、胸が複雑に高鳴る。

ドキドキとした緊張、不安……と同時に、昂揚感とでもいうのだろうか？

間違いなく気持ちが高ぶっている。

It's basically just the character coming to realize that he/she is now in completely different situation where he/she is about to get romantically involved with another person.

Answer (score 2):

If my understanding is correct, a rough English translation of those two lines (the one in bold plus the one before it) would be:

```
Before going to school, I've had the same kind of conversation before.
But this time, something was different.
```

The person is saying that even though the conversation was the same as a previous one, the feelings this time were different.

The bold part is literally "But now, it was not just that", but that sounds a bit awkward in English, hence the non-literal translation above. Another possible translation would be "But this time, there was something more."